# How do I remap cap lock to make other keys act different?

Tags: linux, keyboard, arch-linux

When I press Cap Lock I want WASD to be arrow keys and Q E to be page up and down. Do I use setxkbmap for this? xcape? something else?

Comment: Press and hold (like shift)? Or toggle (like regular caps lock)?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski toggle. I don't think it'll matter if the other keys are capitalized but I 100% would like WASD and a few other keys to do something different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Detailed Answer

There are a few steps to doing this:

1. Use `xmodmap` to remove the caps lock behavior on the caps lock key. Then use `xmodmap` to remap `keycode 66` (caps lock keycode) to a modifier key you don't use. I chose `Hyper_L` because it is not on normal keyboards. For example from my `~/.Xmodmap` config file (where I remap caps lock to `Left Hyper` key):

```
clear lock
keycode 66 = Hyper_L
```

2. Step 1 makes arch interpret caps lock as `Hyper_L`. Modifier keys basically turn on xmodmap mod levels when you press down the key. These mod levels (as opposed to the literal keyboard key) are used by applications to determine which modifiers are being used. Run `xmodmap` command and the output should [look like this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/xmodmap#Modifier_keys). Short answer is to remap `Hyper_L` to control `mod3` because it is unused by default on arch. Do this with these lines in your `.xmodmap`.

```
remove mod4 = Hyper_L
add mod3 = Hyper_L
```

**Note:** *run `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap` for changes to take effect without reboot*

3. Lastly you can use a program like [sxhkd](https://github.com/baskerville/sxhkd) that remaps keystrokes to shell commands to add the functions you would like to specific combinations of your new modifier key. For example in my `sxhkdrc` I have something similar to:

```
hyper + {c,e,f,t,6}
    st -e {chromium,neomutt,lf,vit,top}
```

I use this to map caps lock to launch new windows of various applications.

## TLDR

Install dependencies:

```sh
sudo pacman -Sy xorg-xmodmap sxhkd
```

Configure `xmodmap` - in `~/.Xmodmap` ([XDG compliant if $XDG_CONFIG is set](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/XDG_Base_Directory)):

```
! remap caps_lock to Hyper_l/mod3
clear lock
keycode 66 = Hyper_L

remove mod4 = Hyper_L
add mod3 = Hyper_L
```

Run `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap` for changes to take effect. 
Last, configure `sxhkd` in `~/.config/sxhkdrc` by referring to [the github](https://github.com/baskerville/sxhkd#example-bindings)

Comment: tyvm. I Actually wanted caps lock to toggle (so I don't have to hold it down) but this is acceptable

Answer (score 0):

There are some scenarios to kick-start. I'll continue searching though.

1. The simpler solution is to create another keyboard profile by copying you existing one and changing those keys. You can then press whatever combination to use the other profile.
2. Use this [guide](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/657709/setting-caps-lock-arrows-to-home-pgup-pgdown-end-in-xkb?rq=1) as a reference, although he is not using `capslock` as toggled but pressed instead.
3. Use `capslock` to execute a script which remaps your keys and vice versa.